# Using Google Analytics SDK and Firebase SDK together

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm having a crash on `[FIRApp configure]` step in my AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

Crash gives me completely no information.

But I'm using Google Analytics SDK in my app as well. Maybe that's could be the reason?

So my question is - **is it possible to use both Google Analytics and Firebase SDKs at the same time in one app**?

Thanks.

Comment: Anything relevant in the console logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem.
For GA tracking we should use this lines of code in AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

```
guard let gai = GAI.sharedInstance() else {
  assert(false, "Google Analytics not configured correctly")
}
gai.tracker(withTrackingId: "YOUR_TRACKING_ID")
```

For Firebase tracking we should use

`FirebaseApp.configure()`

in the same place. 
This method is the default method for the Firebase initialization in your application. It takes all the needed for init data from the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file which you should download from your dashboard on the Firebase.
And it was crashing for me on the init step.

**So the actual problem:**
Default `GoogleService-Info.plist` file don't include the `TRACKING_ID` field *which is required for the Firebase initialization*.

**Solution:**
Just add the `TRACKING_ID` property to your `GoogleService-Info.plist` file. The value of this property should have this format: **UA-XXXXXXXX-XX**.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use both Google Analytics and Firebase Analytics without any issue.

**Fix crash:**

You need to download `GoogleService-Info.plist` from Firebase Console and add it to your project. When you call `[FIRApp configure]` it tries to read configuration related data from this plist file. If it is unable to find it, your will crash.

[Instructions on how to download this configuration file](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?hl=en)

Once you download it, simply drag and drop to your project directory in Xcode. This will initialize Firebase and stop your app from crashing.

Comment: nope :) GoogleService-Info.plist already in the project, it's not a reason for the crash

Comment: Can you see if target membership is checked? Also try cleaning build folder.